# Winsock2 - how to open a TCP socket that allows recv() with MSG_WAITALL?

Tags: winsock, recv

In this code:

```
// error checking is omitted

// init Winsock2
WSADATA wsaData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

// connect to server
struct addrinfo *res = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;
ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

getaddrinfo(server_ip, "9999", &hints, &res);
SOCKET client_socket = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);

connect(client_socket, res->ai_addr, (int)res->ai_addrlen);

freeaddrinfo(res);
res = NULL;

// read the data
unsinged int size1;
if (recv(client_socket, (char*)&size1, sizeof(int), MSG_WAITALL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    return WSAGetLastError();
}
```

(note the `MSG_WAITALL` flag in `recv()`) everything works fine, expect for `recv()`. `WSAGetLastError()` returns `WSAEOPNOTSUPP`.
MSDN states that

> Note that if the underlying transport does not support MSG_WAITALL, or if the socket is in a non-blocking mode, then this call will fail with WSAEOPNOTSUPP. Also, if MSG_WAITALL is specified along with MSG_OOB, MSG_PEEK, or MSG_PARTIAL, then this call will fail with WSAEOPNOTSUPP. This flag is not supported on datagram sockets or message-oriented sockets.

But it doesn't look like I'm doing something from this list. Why my `recv()` call doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it doesn't look like I'm doing something from this list.

Yes, you are - the very first item on the list:

> the underlying transport does not support MSG_WAITALL

Microsoft's default TCP transport provider does not support `MSG_WAITALL`.  `recv()`, and Winsock in general, is not limited to just Microsoft's TCP provider. It supports 3rd party providers, and any transport protocols that the provider supports - TCP, UDP, IPX, ICMP, RAW, etc.

When using Microsoft's TCP, if you want `recv()` to wait until all of the requested TCP data has been received, you have to set the socket to blocking mode (its default mode) and then set the `flags` parameter of `recv()` to 0. But even that is not guaranteed, `recv()` can return with fewer bytes than requested, so you should be prepared to call `recv()` in a loop until all intended bytes have actually been received.

Comment: I am aware this is a very old answer but it is nonetheless incorrect. MSG_WAITALL does not imply that the underlying protocol needs to support any kind of message concept. WinSock2 TCP sockets support MSG_WAITALL.

Comment: @BluBb_mADe Microsoft's default transport provider does not support `MSG_WAITALL`, but Winsock2 is not limited to just that provider. Other 3rd party transport providers may support `MSG_WAITALL`. That is why the quoted documentation is written the way it is - it is a contract, not a guarantee. "***IF** the underlying transport ...*" I have updated my answer.

Comment: I would really like to see a source for this claim that default TCP doesn't support MSG_WAITALL because I have been using a `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)` which is arguably the most default way of using one without ipv6 support in combination with `recv(..., MSG_WAITALL)` without errors or issues for years now.

Answer (score -1):

I can assure you that MSTCPIP most certainly supports MSG_WAITALL. You have been misinformed. On Win11 22H2, in the stack trace below which includes both user and kernel mode, notice the last arg to ws2_32!recv is 0x8. That is MSG_WAITALL!

```
00 fffff807`77b34d83     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : tcpip!TcpTlConnectionReceive

01 fffff807`77b33a9c     : 00000000`00000000 ffffa786`4fb6fba0 00000000`00004020 ffffa786`4f8f31c0 : afd!AfdTLPostUserReceive+0xd3

02 fffff807`77b3358f     : 00000000`00000400 000000b7`438ff778 a7865210`00000000 00000000`00004020 : afd!AfdBReceive+0x2cc

03 fffff807`77b4412d     : ffffa786`4fbdc900 ffffa786`4f8f31c0 00000000`00000000 fffff887`00000400 : afd!AfdReceive+0x30f

04 fffff807`6f2934a5     : ffffa786`4fbdc900 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000001 fffff807`6f26a179 : afd!AfdDispatchDeviceControl+0x7d

05 fffff807`6f6cb210     : ffffa786`4fbdc900 00000000`00000002 ffffa786`4fbdc900 ffffa786`52113990 : nt!IofCallDriver+0x55

06 fffff807`6f6c97dc     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00012017 fffff887`6a867520 ffffa786`4fbdc900 : nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x1d0

07 fffff807`6f6c7ab6     : 000000b7`438ff620 0000021e`ccceb430 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!IopXxxControlFile+0x72c

08 fffff807`6f433965     : ffffa786`50671080 fffff887`6a867520 000000b7`438ff5e8 000000b7`438ff298 : nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56

09 00007fff`8234ee54     : 00007fff`7ebd5925 00000000`00000000 00000000`000001f7 0000021e`ccceb430 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25

0a 00007fff`7ebd5925     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`000001f7 0000021e`ccceb430 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x14

0b 00007fff`808b2417     : 00000000`000000ec 0000021e`cccd61c0 00000000`00000400 000000b7`438ff758 : mswsock!WSPRecv+0x2e5

0c 00007ff6`b2c0112e     : 00000000`000000ec 00000000`00000000 00007fff`7fabf4a0 00000000`00000008 : WS2_32!recv+0x197
```