# C/C++ OpenCV Mat(32F) sending through UDP

Tags: c++, c, opencv, sockets

I made Mat(32F) from "reprojectImageTo3D"(one of opencv functions) and I wanna send it through socket(UDP).

How can I send it through UDP?

Should it be sent by each coordinate or Can I send it to Mat at once?

Comment: This [How to send MAT via sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45683471/how-to-send-opencv-mat-throught-socket) may help.  The first answer makes a good recommendation.

Comment: C and C++ are distinct languages -- pick the relevant one, and don't spam unrelated tags.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could first encode the `cv::Mat` object into a vector of unsigned char, then send it via a UDP socket. The receiving endpoint then has to carry out decoding of the `std::vector<uchar>` to produce the original `cv::Mat` (use `cv::imdecode()`).

1. Encoding the cv::Mat object - e.g. JPEG compression using cv::imencode

```
// Assuming you already have a cv::Mat mat object
std::vector<uchar> buf;
std::vector<int> params;
params.push_back(cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
params.push_back(50); // compression quality, ranges between 0-100

if (!cv::imencode(".jpg", mat, buf, params)) {
  std::cout << "JPEG compression failed.\n";
}
```

2. Sending the compressed image data via UDP

```
// Create UDP socket
int sockfd_;
if ((sockfd_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
  perror("socket creation failed\n");
  return false;
}

struct sockaddr_in addr;
// Populate addr variable with endpoint's URI
/* TODO */

// Send data
if (!sendto(sockfd_, (const uchar*)buf.data(), buf.size(), MSG_DONTWAIT,
            (const struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr))) {
  std::cout << "Failed to send frame to client.\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for reply
What I have is a 32bit float, can I get it in uchar?
and Can I compress it on JPEG?

thanks a lot!

Comment: JPEG can't store floating point values, and it's lossy.

Comment: Then How can I send Mat(32 float format) through UDP?

Comment: @wooki The documentation says "32-bit float (CV_32F) images can be saved in PFM, TIFF, OpenEXR, and Radiance HDR formats; 3-channel (CV_32FC3) TIFF images will be saved using the LogLuv high dynamic range encoding (4 bytes per pixel)" -- didn't you read it?