# WinSock2's recv with MSG_WAITALL flag returns incomplete packet with no error

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp, winsock2

I'm using `WinSock2.h` to receive data from a TCP socket. Here's the the code for creating the socket and receiving from it:

```
int Socket_Init(SOCKET * pSocket) {
    struct addrinfo lHints;
    struct addrinfo *lResult = nullptr;
    memset(&lHints, 0, sizeof(lHints));

    lHints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    lHints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    lHints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    if (getaddrinfo(ADDR, PORT_ID, &lHints, &lResult) != 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    *pSocket = socket(lResult->ai_family, lResult->ai_socktype, lResult->ai_protocol);
    if (*pSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        return -2;
    }

    // Set receive timeout.
    uint32_t timeout = 10000;
    if (setsockopt(*pSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        return -3;
    }
    
    // Set send timeout.
    if (setsockopt(*pSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        return -4;
    }

    if (connect(*pSocket, lResult->ai_addr, (int)lResult->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        return -5;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int Socket_Receive(char * buf, int len, SOCKET * pSocket) {
    if (*pSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        return -1;
    }

    int nBytesReceived = recv(*pSocket, buf, len, MSG_WAITALL);
    if (nBytesReceived == 0) {
        return -2;
    } else if (nBytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        if (WSAECONNABORTED == LAST_ERROR || WSAECONNRESET == LAST_ERROR) {
            return -3;
        } else {
            return -4;
        }
    }

    return nBytesReceived;
}
```

I use this code to receive packets of 131130 bytes. Using Wireshark, I can see that the incomplete packet happens when there is a retransmission on the last or second-to-last segmented packet (the stack splits the message into chunks of 1460 bytes + header). When this happens, `recv()` returns (131130 - size retransmitted) instead of 131130. If I do another read for the number of bytes missing, I can get them without problem.

My confusion comes from the fact that I'm using the `MSG_WAITALL` flag, which doesn't seem to work fully. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv), `recv()` with the `MSG_WAITALL` flag will return only if:

- The buffer supplied by the caller is completely full.
- The connection has been closed.
- The request has been canceled or an error occurred.

But I receive no error, the connection is still open, and the buffer isn't full.

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214356/winsock2-how-to-open-a-tcp-socket-that-allows-recv-with-msg-waitall), where the replyer says that `MSG_WAITALL` is not supported by TCP sockets and to use 0 instead of `MSG_WAITALL`. I tried it, but this resulted in even more retries from my code. Moreover, if it was not supported, then I believe the `recv()` function should fail immediately with `WSAEOPNOTSUPP`, which it doesn't.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I suspect most people would advise you to just not use MSG_WAITALL. You don't really need it. You can write your own waitall_recv function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @user253751. Yeah, waitall_recv is basically what I implemented to fix the issue, I just wanted to make sure that the problem didn't come from my implementation before forcing this workaround.

Comment: On a side note, your `Socket_Init()` is leaking resources on failure. You are not closing `*pSocket`, or freeing `lResult`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, This is simplified code for the sake of the question, thanks for the note, though!